# Is it possible to show subsections with page numbers in TOC using XSL:FO?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am using XSL FO to generate PDF file. I am trying to show the chapter, section1, subsection1, subsubsection1 with Page numbers. But I am unable to do it. Here is the code that I am trying to achieve. But I can able to see the page number and internal link only for the "Chapter" part alone. See the below image. I want to show the page number and internal destination link for subsections too. Any help?[image]

```
<xsl:template name="genTOC">
    <fo:block break-before='page'>
        <fo:block font-size="16pt" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">TABLE OF CONTENTS</fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="//chapter|//section1|//subsection1|//subsubsection1">
            <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{generate-id(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="index"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
                    <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
                </fo:basic-link>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <fo:block id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="section1">
    <fo:block id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subsection1">
    <fo:block id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subsubsection1">
    <fo:block id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Have you checked the XSL-FO to see whether corresponding IDs are being generated? Which formatter are you using?

Comment: Examine your output XSL-FO file once more and check fo:block/@id from `section1`, `subsection1`, `subsubsection1` is normally generated by your main template. If they are not generated, the PDF generation step should display the @id reference error.

Comment: @TonyGraham- I have checked the fo and I see the id's are generated but not set to the <fo:block> of the section , subsection.. etc.

Comment: @tmakita - I have checked the fo and I see the id's are generated but not set to the <fo:block> of the section , subsection.. etc

Comment: Then your main stylesheet does not applied to `section1` and `subsection1` at all. If you are using Saxon, using trace option will be useful. In JAXP transformation, use `<attribute name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/traceListenerClass" value="net.sf.saxon.trace.XSLTTraceListener"/>`.

Comment: It depends on what is the value of "index". You are outputting that element in your XSL. Also using the tab character will not work. You need to layout as a table or use a list with a fixed spacing for the label (which would be the index)

Comment: @KevinBrown The value of the index is just 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1, etc... I tried removing the index and still it didn't work.

Comment: Leave in the index, remove the two tabs, they are meaningless in an xsl fo document.

Comment: You say the Id's are set but not to the block. The question is what are they in the TOC and the rest of the FO? Do they match or not?